# How to skip cells in a lambda shift rolling function in pandas based off multiple column criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe which is a list of althete times:

```
Name      Time     Excuse     Injured       Margin
John       15       nan           0            1
John       18       nan           0            5
John       30       leg injury    1            11
John       16       nan           0            4
John       40       nan           0            18
John       15       nan           0            3
John       22       nan           0            6
```

I then am using a function to get the mean of the previous last 5 times shifted:

```
df['last5'] = df.groupby(['Name']).Time.apply(
    lambda x: x.shift().rolling(5, min_periods=1).mean().fillna(.5))
```

This works but I am hoping to perform the same calculation but I want to ignore the `Time` if there is an `Excuse`, `Injured = 1` or `Margin >10`.

My Expected output would be:

```
Name      Time       Excuse     Injured     Margin     last5
John       15                     0            1         .5
John       18                     0            5         15
John       30       leg injury    1            11        16.5
John       16                     0            4         16.5
John       40                     0            18        16.33
John       15                     0            3         16.33
John       22                     0            6         16
```

Can I just add a condition onto the end of the orginal function? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can filter the dataframe according to criteria *before* applying the `rolling` calculation
2. Use `bfill()` to backwards fill the `NaN` values as required:

---

```
df['last5'] = (df[(df['Excuse'].isnull()) & (df['Injured'] != 1) & (df['Margin'] <= 10)]
               .groupby(['Name']).Time.apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(5, min_periods=1)
                                             .mean().fillna(.5)))
df['last5'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['last5'].bfill()
df
Out[1]: 
   Name  Time      Excuse  Injured  Margin      last5
0  John    15         NaN        0       1   0.500000
1  John    18         NaN        0       5  15.000000
2  John    30  leg injury        1      11  16.500000
3  John    16         NaN        0       4  16.500000
4  John    40         NaN        0      18  16.333333
5  John    15         NaN        0       3  16.333333
6  John    22         NaN        0       6  16.000000
```

Comment: Thanks David this looks great. I think my only issue is with the `bfill()` fuction. I have a list of different names not in order so is there a way to `bfill` by name? would that be something like `df['last5'] = df['last5'].groupby(['Name']).bfill()`?

Comment: or rather `df['last5'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['last5'].bfill()`

Comment: @SOK yes, good point. You should use `df['last5'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['last5'].bfill()`. I have updated my answer.